# Extracting href attr or converting node to character list

Tags: html, r, rvest

I try to extract some information from the website

```
library(rvest)
library(XML)
url <- "http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/wybory-prezydenckie/xcnpc"
html <- html(url)

nodes <- html_nodes(html, ".listItemSolr") 
nodes
```

I get "list" of 30 parts of HTML code. I want from each element of the "list" extract last href attribute, so for the 30. element it would be

```
<a href="http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/kraj/w-sobote-prezentacja-hasla-i-programu-wyborczego-komorowskiego/tvgcq" title="W sobotę prezentacja hasła i programu wyborczego Komorowskiego">
```

so I want to get string

```
"http://wiadomosci.onet.pl/kraj/w-sobote-prezentacja-hasla-i-programu-wyborczego-komorowskiego/tvgcq"
```

The problem is `html_attr(nodes, "href")` doesn't work (I get vector of NA's). So I thought about regex but the problem is that `nodes` isn't the character list.

```
class(nodes)
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

I tried

```
xmlToList(nodes)
```

but it doesn't work either.

So my question is: how can I extract this url with some function created for HTML? Or, if it is not possible how can I get convert XMLNodeSet to character list?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try searching inside nodes' children:

```
nodes <- html_nodes(html, ".listItemSolr") 

sapply(html_children(nodes), function(x){
  html_attr( x$a, "href")
})
```

#### Update

Hadley suggested using elegant pipes:

```
html %>%  
  html_nodes(".listItemSolr") %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = "./a") %>% 
  html_attr("href")
```

Comment: Thank you! It's exactly what I wanted :)

Comment: This could be more simply written as `html %>% html_nodes(".listItemSolr") %>% html_node("a") %>% html_attr("href")`

Comment: Not the same result - (118 instead of just 30, because we have to move down one level.) But yes: `html  %>% html_nodes(".listItemSolr")  %>% html_nodes(xpath = "./a") %>% html_attr("href")` is OK. Thanks @hadley!

Answer (score 2):

Package XML function `getHTMLLinks()` can do virtually all the work for us, we just have to write the xpath query.  Here we query all the node attributes to determine if any contains "listItemSolr", then select the parent node for the href query.

```
getHTMLLinks(url, xpQuery = "//@*[contains(., 'listItemSolr')]/../a/@href")
```

In `xpQuery` we are doing the following:

- `//@*[contains(., 'listItemSolr')]` query all node attributes for *listItemSolr*
- `/..` select the parent node
- `/a/@href` get the href links

Comment: I think in `rvest` there is a trade-off between power and readability. With pure `xpath` you need an extra moment to see that class is missing in the epression (it should be `//@class[contains(., 'listItemSolr')]/../a/@href`). But in this case the result is still the same.

Comment: Right.  I saw that too but since we wouldn't know it's in `class` I tried to show how to find it otherwise