# Scraping embeded html table in R

Tags: html, xml, r, parsing, web-scraping

*I am fairly new to scraping/parsing HTML in R. I am trying to get data from the Career Receiving Statistics and Career Rushing Statistics' tables from http://totalfootballstats.com/PlayerWR.asp?id=1218565.
I know about the read readHTMLtable function but both these tables are embedded in so much junk and I can't seem to get past the children nodes of the root.*

EDIT: the above problem has been solved. However for the website http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/a-index.html I am trying to loop through all players and access their data. I'm running into trouble in accessing their respective url links. I have tried:

```
fb=htmlParse("http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/a-index.html")
p1=getNodeSet(fb,'//pre')
con = textConnection(xmlValue(p1[[100]]))
players100 = read.table(con)
```

But this results in the error "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : 
  line 3 did not have 5 elements"

The other thing I tried is:

```
 links <- xpathSApply(fb, "//a/@href")
```

But I feel like there should be a better way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO and welcome to the world of scraping data from horrible sites. If you show some indication (via code, not words) that you actually tried something you might get some concrete help (this is not a code writing service).

Comment: I am now referencing the website provided in the answer below but from the original player page I have:

fb=htmlParse("http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/a-index.html")
p1=getNodeSet(fb,'//pre')

From here I kind of want to make a table with all the players, years, and attached urls. I tried making a table for each block like such.
con = textConnection(xmlValue(p1[[100]]))
players100 = read.table(con)  
But this results in the error: "Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  : line 3 did not have 5 elements"

Comment: @user3451457 - It's almost always `//a/@href` or `//link/@href` to get the linked url

Comment: Also, have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29042027/extracting-href-attr-or-converting-node-to-character-list/29051291#29051291) for how to get all the links on a page, and then have a look at [W3 Schools XML Tutorials](http://www.w3schools.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well here's the same player from a different website, much much cleaner.  The data doesn't match though, so someone got it wrong.  My money's on totalfootballstats.com. Choose your resources wisely!

```
readHTMLTable(
    "http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/doyle-aaron-1.html"
)
# $receiving
#  Year     School Conf Class Pos  G Rec Yds  Avg TD Att Yds  Avg TD Plays Yds  Avg TD
# 1 1988 Miami (FL)  Ind        WR 11   1  12 12.0  0   1  34 34.0  0     2  46 23.0  0
# 2 1989 Miami (FL)  Ind        WR 11   8  93 11.6  1                     8  93 11.6  1

# $kick_ret
#   Year     School Conf Class Pos  G Ret Yds Avg TD Ret Yds Avg TD
# 1 1988 Miami (FL)  Ind        WR 11   1   8 8.0  0               
# 2 1989 Miami (FL)  Ind        WR 11
```

For specific requests, it looks like you can a construct a valid URL like this, which will also construct the path for multiple players at once.

```
## base URI 
u <- "http://www.sports-reference.com"
## player first and last names
first <- "bill"
last <- "adams"
## use sprintf() to make all the paths at once
fullPath <- sprintf("%s/cfb/players/%s-%s-1.html", u, first, last)
## read the table - I think you'll need to loop readHTMLTable() though
readHTMLTable(fullPath)
# $receiving
#  Year School Conf Class Pos  G Rec Yds  Avg TD Att Yds Avg TD Plays Yds  Avg TD
# 1 1969 Dayton  Ind        WR 10   1   3  3.0  1                    1   3  3.0  1
# 2 1970 Dayton  Ind        WR 10   4  42 10.5  1                    4  42 10.5  1
```

Comment: I initially looked at this site but chose not to use it because I couldn't figure out how to access each player's data from the original player page: http://www.sports-reference.com/cfb/players/a-index.html. Each block of players is in some <pre...> block that I don't know how to access?

Comment: @user3451457 - I added  a possible method. You should probably investigate a few of the site's paths first though, with the web inspector just to make sure it's  consistent

Comment: That looks like a great method but I want to figure out how to actually GET the player names instead of entering them manually. I have edit my original question with what I have tried for that